# Conditionally enable autoplay when using oEmbed in a custom widget

Tags: widgets, hooks, oembed

I'd like to have all oEmbed urls (youtube, vimeo, soundcloud, etc.) behave as they usually behave, with one exception.

In my theme I've created a widget that gets data from a given post. The post content is rendered through `the_content()`.

I'm planning to add a checkbox that allows to set the autoplay for any oEmbed media contained in the selected post.

The only thing I don't know is how to handle this :)
I suppose I must work with some filter, but:

1. I don't know which filter I should use
2. I don't know ho to hook to the filter **only** when rendering the widget.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WP Oembed not passing through the "autoplay=1" variable](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5362/wp-oembed-not-passing-through-the-autoplay-1-variable)

Comment: I don't want to handle the autoplay argument, if passed in the url. I want to autoplay media, regardless the argument and only when I'm using it in a widget: quite different than the other question, isn't it?